# including tests at runtime in specflow

Tags: c#, specflow

I have different azure pipelines for different environment, that run specflow tests. I am using `Nunit` with specflow.  I get information about environment in tests by reading pipeline variables. I would like to run a specific scenario for a specific environment by passing tags or by some other way.

I was able to search a solution for excluding a test based on environment by using specflow `tags` and `unitTestRuntimeProvider` and calling its `TestIgnore` method and define this whole logic in `[BeforScenario()]` hook

Similarly , how do I **include** tests ( using tags or some other way) to run at runtime in Specflow?

(I understand `tags` can be used to run specific tests but they will be run in all environments. I would like to select tests at runtime based on tag and a variable that holds environment value. I already have this value in test)

Comment: How are you running the tests? What have you tried?

Comment: @Greg Burghardt  Tests are run  by pipeline through a task . I am using `NUnit 3.13` .  I could not even find a concept to start thats why I posted .  Why would someone want to close this question? It is valid question with details and if required more details can be provided

Comment: The term "pipeline" is very general. Can you clarify this? Are you using Jenkins? Azure DevOps? Something else?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details about how these tests are executed.